# Interesting property of partitions of $n$

Tags: integer-partitions

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Show that the number of partitions of $n$, having one part more than $\frac n2$, is equal to the number of partitions of $n$ having more than $\frac n2$ parts.

The difficulty is in the fact that, a partition is not only finding the number of solutions to $x_1+\cdots+x_k=n, x_i\ge1~\forall i$, but that it has to be unordered. I am stuck there.

Comment: conjugation${}$?

Comment: Have a look at [Young tableau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau) or Ferrers diagrams.  Such relations often yield quickly to transposing such figures, which I suspect is what @LordSharktheUnknown is thinking.

Comment: Could you explain a little more. Couldn't understand your hints.

Comment: You can read the Young tableau of a partition from the other side, which can allow you to pair one partition in the first group to another partition in the second group. This can show that the number of partitions in both groups are equal.